# can you do this seemingly simple Ant copy task without using ant-contrib's foreach?

Tags: ant, copy, wildcard

I have a source directory with a bunch of plugins. Each plugin has its own `lib` directory. I want the contents of each of those `lib` directories to be merged into a single `lib` directory within my build. In theory you'd do something like this:

```
<copy todir="build/web/lib">
    <fileset dir="web/plugins/*/lib/" includes="**/*" />
</copy>
```

However, Ant chokes when the dir attribute includes a wildcard. Is ant-contrib the only alternative, or can you make this work with vanilla ant?

Choke message is `build.xml:28: [...]/web/plugins/*/lib does not exist.`

Comment: This is a fine question, but in future please leave the venting out.  Remember: all software sucks, all hardware sucks; we know this all too well already.

Comment: you're right, and most of the time I can avoid venting. But somehow Ant really gets under my skin in a way that few languages can -- except maybe XSLT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dir=` attribute of a fileset doesn't take a wildcard - hence the error you see.  You need to specify a single directory, in this case `web/plugins`, and use a slightly different wildcard for the includes:

```
<copy todir="build/web/lib">
    <fileset dir="web/plugins" includes="*/lib/**/*" />
</copy>
```

If you need to alter the paths as you copy, you can use a [mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html), for example the `flattenmapper` will give you file names with all leading directory information stripped off.

Comment: A regexp mapper might be worth looking at too, something like: `<regexpmapper from=".*/lib/(.*)" to="\1" handledirsep="true" />`

Comment: moving the wildcard into the includes section doesn't work because then each source directory is included in the target directory. The goal is to merge each of the source directories' contents into a single target directory.

Comment: @Jeoff - As I mentioned in the answer - you need to add the flattenmapper if you want all the source directories' contents in a single target directory.

Comment: can't use flattenmapper because the plugin directories include subdirs of their own, and files in those subdirs need to be merged in with the same path. (The root of the problem is that the path that gets copied needs to use the plugin dir as root, whereas your suggestion uses one dir higher as root.) I do appreciate the help though, and it sounds like your approach in combination with a regexpmapper that strips the first path element from the filename would do the trick.

Comment: @Jeoff - I get the idea - regexmapper should do the trick for that.